# Vertical gestures + vertical scrolling

Tags: java, android, gesture

I am currently developing a rss-reader-app and got stuck on a problem:
In a special activity i need to

- swipe left/right to switch to the previous/next article
- scroll up/down to scroll through the current article
- build some custom gestures (For example swipe a "S" to share this article)

Is there any way to get those 3 requirements build in? 
The problem is when I listen for the custom gestures either the swipe or the scroll stops working depending on the orientation of the GestureOverlayView.
I hope you understand what I mean!

Regards
Manu